# Can I use S3 lifecycle policy and versioning at the same time?

Tags: version-control, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want my S3 bucket to be version controlled for protection against accidental modifications. Also I want that objects in my S3 be archived to Glacier after 30 days.

When I went to enable versioning, it said

> Once enabled, Versioning cannot be disabled and you will not be able to add Lifecycle Rules for this bucket.

But, can I add a lifecycle rule for the bucket and then enable versioning.

Also, how will restore work in that case. Say for example, on day 1 I have in my bucket files A, B, C. On day 20 I have file A, B1, C1, D. On day 30 the objects are moved to S3. Now when I do a restore say on day 40, will I still have all the versions of file B in my bucket ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon S3 Now Supports Lifecycle Rules for Versioning

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/05/20/amazon-s3-now-supports-lifecycle-rules-for-versioning/

> Amazon S3 now supports lifecycle rules for versioning. This means that you can now use lifecycle rules for S3 buckets regardless of whether they are enabled for versioning or not.

Answer (score 0):

### Versioned bucket and lifecycle policy not allowed at the same time

AWS documentation states, combination of versioned bucket and lifecycle is not possible.

Trying to enable versioning on a bucket with lifecycle rules (using Management Console) will instruct you first to remove the rules.

Adding lifecycle rules into versioned bucket is not provided.

### How to archive content on versioned bucket

Being at the same situation, I use following solution:

1) Move first all versions into "flat bucket"
2) Archive to Glacier from flat bucket.

Flat bucket is a concept allowing to store versions on non versioned bucket. OpenStack project [swift](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/overview_object_versioning.html) does it in a way, that each key from versioned bucket gets special name on flat one in a shape of `<hexprefix><original_key_name>/<epochtimeinmilis>`

`<hexprefix>` are three characters long hexadecimal number (zero padded) telling you length of original key name. This allows you to use arbitrary key names on versioned bucket, even with a name resembling format used on flat bucket. The prefix is always here to tell you, how far to read key name to get the original name.

In my solution, I used a bit different pattern to denote last modified time.

### Advice - when moving to flat bucket, pack files into larger chunks

As Amazon Glacier has some overhead, for which you have to pay, It is recommended to pack archived content into larger files. I use simple tar. Break even point for file size is about 16 kB, smaller files are stored in Amazon Glacier at higher cost, than in AWS S3 (the point was calculated before last prices went down, expect it now to be even higher).

Comment: This is not true any more. "You can add lifecycle configuration to nonversioned buckets and versioning-enabled buckets. " http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html